# Send data to the next page's form in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have two models Log and LogDetail (They are connected via an FK). This is the flow that I wan to create:

1. Create a Log object, and redirect to it's detail page
2. Inside detail page there is a link to create LogDetail object(s)
3. When the user hits the create LogDetail link it should use Log ID as the default value of the FK in form

the problem is that I don't know how to send/receive Log ID

Comment: Could you please attach your code?

Comment: Hi! Please provide some context of your problem, show your research effort and code attempt
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

@Kurosh

**Option1**
For your flow you have two options. One is pass Log ID in your url path and use urlpatterns to get the id.
For example in your template:

```
<form action='url/to/createview/<int:log_id>' method="post">
```

In your urls.py

```
path('url/to/createview/<int:log_id>',views.create_log_detail);
```

you can change `url/to/createview` as per your need.

**Option2**
On details page add the logID in your form input field as hidden field and value will come in the form to your logDetail create view as a post variable.
example:

```
<input name='log_id' value="{{ object.pk }}" type="hidden">
```

You can then process this value in your view method.

I hope this is helpful. For more specific answer you will have to share the following code:

1. Your view method for creating LogDetail object
2. Your urls.py
3. Your template html file for detail page of Log Object.